# How can I send fax using Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, fax, interfax

I found interfax in the npm. But not sure is it that I need. Can someone help me to find a right way for sending faxes using node+express?

Comment: The interfax sounds like the way to go

Comment: This seems quite opinion-based. Right way to send basically just means using a service of some sort; interfax is one of those. No-one can really definitively give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will take a look at source code of the interfax library, you can see that this library is using native node.js module `https`. You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

So you do not need `express` at all. Just go ahead with the documentation in the readme file.

But if you want to send fax after some endpoint call, you can do something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const InterFAX = require('interfax');

// Initialize using parameters
const interfax = new InterFAX({
  username: '...',
  password: '...'
});

app.get('/sendFax', (req, res) => {
  // Send test file
 interfax.outbound.deliver({
   faxNumber: '+11111111112',
   file: 'folder/fax.txt'
 })
 .then(fax => {
   res.send('Fax sended');
 })
 .catch(error => {
   res.send('Error: ', error);
 });
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you